# Relay fragment variables

Tags: javascript, relayjs

**Link Github issue:** https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1218

We have encountered an strange behaviour of Relay. I will try to explain the best I can.

So we have an "main" relay container that fetches the data for corresponding store, and also includes and fragment from Ticket container.
Ticket container render out custom table that has filter and sorting. So you can see that in StoreFrom component StoreTicketList container is import all required props are passed like Store fragment.

The problem occurs when you try to filter StoreList Ticket, I mean set filter or sort relay variables.
You will get this error:

Warning: RelayContainer: component `TicketList` was rendered with variables that differ from the variables used to fetch fragment `Store`. The fragment was fetched with variables `{"first":5,"after":null,"last":null,"before":null,"sort":null,"filter":null}`, but rendered with variables `{"first":5,"after":null,"last":null,"before":null,"sort":null,"filter":{"authorAccount":{"email":{"__e":"wrongEmail@email.com"}}}}`. This can indicate one of two possibilities: 
 - The parent set the correct variables in the query - `TicketList.getFragment('Store', {...})` - but did not pass the same variables when rendering the component. Be sure to tell the component what variables to use by passing them as props: `<TicketList ... first={...} after={...} last={...} before={...} sort={...} filter={...} />`.
 - You are intentionally passing fake data to this component, in which case ignore this warning.

But those filter/sort variables are on StoreTicketList and they arent passed dow from parent to child container like in this case Store container to StoreListTicket container.

```
export class StoreForm extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const { Viewer: { store } } = props;

    this.state = {
      number: store && store.number !== null ? store.number : '',
    };
  }

  handleInsert = (model) => {
    console.log('Form mutation model : ', model);
  };

  render() {
    const { Viewer, relay: { variables: { update } } } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Form>
          <FormTitle title='Store Info' />
          <FormBody>
            <TextField
              required
              fullWidth
              name='number'
              value={this.state.number}
              floatingLabelText='Number'
            />
            <StoreTicketList Store={this.props.Viewer.store} />
          </FormBody>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

StoreForm container (main container):

```
export default Relay.createContainer(StoreForm, {
  initialVariables: {
    id: null,
    update: false
  },
  prepareVariables({ id = null }) {
    return { id, update: (id !== null) };
  },
    fragments: {
        Viewer: (variables) => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Viewer {
        store(id: $id) @include(if: $update) {
          id,
          number
          ${StoreTIcketList.getFragment('Store')}
        }
      }
    `
    }
});
```

Ticket container:

```
export const StoreTicketList = Relay.createContainer(TicketList, {
  initialVariables: {
    first: 5,
    after: null,
    last: null,
    before: null,
    sort: null,
    filter: null
  },
    fragments: {
        Store: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Store {
        ticketConnection(first: $first, after: $after, last: $last, before: $before, sort: $sort, filter: $filter) {
          count,
          pageInfo {
            hasNextPage,
            hasPreviousPage,
            startCursor,
            endCursor
          },
          edges{
            node{
              created,
              subject
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
    }
});
```

We have built our own Connection Table HOC component that renders table for each container. In this component there are also sort and filter function that are using `this.props.relay.setVariables()`. 
So the StoreListTicket is rendering as an ConnectionTable and it passes down the relay prop object, and if user clicks on a table colum header, component is generating an array of sort objects.

```
function connectionTableHOC(ComposedComponent) {

  class EnhanceTable extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
     super(props);
    }

    sortHandler = (sortArray) => {
     const { relay, relay: { variables } } = this.props;

     relay.setVariables({
       first: variables.first || variables.last,
       after: null,
       last: null,
       before: null,
       sort: sortArray
     });
   };

   filterHandler = (filterObj) => {
     const { relay, relay: { variables } } = this.props;

     relay.setVariables({
      first: variables.first || variables.last,
      after: null,
      last: null,
      before: null,
      filter: filterObj
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're calling `setVariables` somewhere, but it isn't clear from the example code where that's happening. Can you also show the code that calls `setVariables`? This will make it clear where the variables are changing and why the parent and child components disagree about their values.

Comment: I have updated the post with the code you have requested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out you need to do **two** things:

First, pass the props into the component, as described by Joe Savona. I'm using react-relay-router, so for me that was a matter of adding this line

```
<Route path="interviews">
  <IndexRoute component={InterviewsList} queries={ViewerQuery} />
  <Route path=":id" component={InterviewSession} queries={NodeViewerQuery}
    render={({ props }) => props ? <InterviewSession {...props} /> : <Loading />}/> // <--- this line
</Route>
```

Second, you must  inject the variable's values into the `getFragment` function call, like so:

```
fragments: {
    Viewer: (variables) => Relay.QL`
  fragment on Viewer {
    store(id: $id) @include(if: $update) {
      id,
      number
      ${StoreTIcketList.getFragment('Store', {... variables})} // <---- this thing!
    }
  }
`
}
```

Note that if you're using `getFragment` inside of your root query, `variables` will be argument number two:

```
const NodeViewerQuery = {
  node: (component, variables) => Relay.QL`query { // <---- extra "component" argument
    node(id: $id) {
      ${component.getFragment('node', {...variables})}
    }
  }`,
```

(This answer crossposted from https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1218)

Comment: I have added those changes you proposed and i have the same thing/problem ... You can take a look at my repo from last post... I dont see why passing variables from parent to child container should work, beacuse they are using different set of initial variables to render the container.. Store container has only `id` but ticket container has `filter, first, last, after and before`. so those are tied to ticket container. 
initially ticket container is renderd with `filter: null` if you updated the filter var first time relay doesn't complain only when you updated the filter var second time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the parent component (the `EnhanceTable`) is setting the variables for its child (the `StoreTicketList`). This means that when the child renders it tries to render using the default variables, while the parent has fetched a different set of variables (sorted/filtered). The solution is to have `EnhanceTable` tell the rendered component what sort/filter it is using:

```
function connectionTableHOC(ComposedComponent) {

  class EnhanceTable extends React.Component {
    ...

    render() {
      return (
        <ComposedComponent 
          {...this.props} 
          filterVarName={filterValue}
          sortVarName={sortValue}
        />
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, will try the solution and report, but something i realized, relay will show this warning and will render the component tree with old this.props.relay.variables.filter variables and it will rerender the same component tree with the correct "new" this.props.relay.variables.filter

Comment: i have tried to pass filter variables from the Parent `Enhance` component and I still hit the same problem, and I tied to pass the filter props from many other places and still, nothing...

Comment: Hmm. It's still not quite clear from your code example exactly how you're calling `connectionTableHOC`. Can you paste the code to show how StoreForm renders StoreTicketList?

Comment: I have tried to isolate the problem, and have created small example of the models on GraphQL side and Containers/Components on the frontend side.

Here is the repo link: https://github.com/mario-jerkovic/Relay-FragmentVariables

If you uncomment the code inside `/js/routes/AppHomeRoute.js` and `/js/app.js`, relay wont complaint about different variables, the only difference between working and not working code the the react-router-relay.